# How to force Windows to save desktop icon positions?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, desktop, icons, layout

Is there a way to force Windows to save desktop icon positions?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, and thanks for contributing! Note that, while [answering your own questions is perfectly OK](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions), you should format your post as such - a question and an answer. So please rewrite your post so that it poses a question or describes a problem, then post the solution as an answer. Also don't forget to accept the answer (by clicking on the checkmark outline next to it), so that others who find this know that the solution worked for you.

Comment: There's also a small shell extension that adds "Save Desktop Icon Layout" and "Restore Desktop Icon Layout" options to the context menu of the "My Computer" icon. You can get it [here](http://download.cnet.com/Icon-Restore/3000-2072_4-10163499.html), for example.

Comment: The fact that these hacks work is a sad comment on the basic UI here.  Anyway, just in-case, you can also take a peek at this little [Desktop Restore](http://www.midiox.com/index.htm?http://www.midiox.com/desktoprestore.htm) tool I found in a forum some-place.  You can save the settings to a file -- Which you can then take with you to a new PC, etc, etc. Great idea!

Comment: Not possible to answer, but a comment will do. I created a very lightweight service that automatically saves/restores the positions after a resolution change. Check it out: https://github.com/TomONeill/persistentdesktopicons

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can simply **right-click the Desktop & click Refresh**. This saves the icon positions (at least it does on XP, also confirmed on Windows 7).

Here's a simple way to confirm that this method works:

- Move an icon
- Kill `explorer.exe` (& restart it, if it doesn't auto-restart)
- Notice icon moves back (because it wasn't saved)
- Move icon again
- Right-click on the Desktop -> click Refresh
- Kill `explorer.exe` (& restart)
- Notice icon doesn't move back (since this time it was saved before killing explorer)

Comment: how to restart explorer.exe after it is killed from taskmanager.. I see no way to restart.. as start menu disappears.. (windows 7)

Comment: In "Task Manager" click "File" menu option and select "Run new task". And then type "explorer" and hit enter.

Comment: Great on Windows 10 too...

Comment: all my life, are you even kidding me? it works, why must I have suffered these many years?

Comment: You are god among mens

Comment: I am surprised about this solution! Years ago i was using the small tool dips.exe "desktop icon position saver", which actually injects a dll into explorer.exe to get and restore desktop icon positions. You got my up-vote, thanks!

Comment: Explorer positions can be wiped out instantly by a new driver install and many other things..  
Windows needs to offer a 'save icon positions' context on desktop (and maybe offer different icon position 'profiles' while they are at it). They have only needed this for 30 years.. no rush i guess? "Let's rely on 3rd party devs/utilities instead.." SMH..

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Win10. On the contrary refreshing immediately moves my magnify.exe icon to some place..

Answer (score 31):

There is a nice, tiny standalone [**DesktopOK**](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopOK) app,
which can **SAVE** the config-file (in same folder), and then **Restore** it whenever you want..

Comment: This works great for my case, where I often dock and undock my work laptop. Switching between the native laptop display and two larger monitors screws up Win7's placement of icons and they end up all over the place (pretty pathetic, if you ask me). Using DesktopOK, you can save several "sessions" for various monitor configurations and resolutions, and restore them as and when needed. Doesn't need installation, just run when you want to save or restore.

Comment: Sadly I've found DesktopOK to crash win10 at version 4.41

Comment: DesktopOK version 4.71 seems to work OK in Windows 10. There's also [Iconoid](http://www.sillysot.com/), which can save & restore Relative icon positions, which I found handy when switching from single laptop screen to laptop screen + large monitor.

Comment: I've tested DesktopOK 4.73 on W10 and it does NOT work. The restore function doesn't do anything.

Comment: DesktopOK 9.11 working great on Windows 11. I especially love the transparency of saved .dok files. A typical line: `music videos=348,821`

Answer (score 14):

Just installed [DesktopRestore](http://www.midiox.com/index.htm?http://www.midiox.com/desktoprestore.htm) from midiox, which works fine on Windows 7 and 10. Just right click on the Desktop to see the menu -

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted. This is a great answer and an awesome solution. I have been using Jamie O'Connell's Desktop icon Save and Restore for over a DECADE now, and still using on Win7 x64. It's invaluable especially for when you are switching between a multi-monitor setup at work and a single-monitor (laptop) at home. You can set up different layouts that are super easy to restore contextually based on the monitor setup. The link to the (free) application is on Jamie's website: http://www.midiox.com/html/desktop.htm

Comment: I did not downvote, but this solution no longer works in Win10

Comment: That's not true. I use it on Windows 10 and it seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: On Win10 menus seem to behave weirdly (won't drop down; double clicking any of them instead changes language) while keeping the program window open during screen changes.

Comment: Downvotes may come from the fact that currently 26 of 64 engines in [https://www.virustotal.com/](https://www.virustotal.com/) report the chip.de installer as malicious, probably due to adware injected by download site. I've edited the answer and changed the link to the official site.

Comment: Tested on W10 and this works! unlike DesktopOK which doesn't...

Answer (score 9):

A way to force Windows to save desktop icon positions without using third-party utilities:

1. Open Notepad and enter some text, so that *if* you were to close it, it would show a confirmation dialog.
2. Attempt to log off.
3. Notepad (and possibly other applications) will ask you whether you want to save changes.
4. Click Cancel. This will prevent Windows from logging off.

The desktop icon positions are now saved. It happens because it's one of the things that Windows does when logging off, and it happens before actually logging off.

This may be helpful when you have just tidied up your desktop, because if Windows Explorer crashes, modifications to the desktop icon positions are lost.

Comment: I think the [solution of Anonymous](http://superuser.com/a/468420/62130) is much simpler, and it actually works, I just tried that. :) Btw., interesting one.

Comment: That one is indeed simpler ;) . This one could still be useful though, in the off case the simpler one stops working in a future version of Windows.

Comment: I like the way you think, I've always logged out & back in (or restarted) - yet the refresh trick also works - all this time!

Answer (score 4):

An issue affecting **Windows 10** was connected to **ESET** Antivirus (and their similar products). Once the AV removes a trojan/virus, the icon and folder (registry) settings become corrupted and there is no going back.

Fortunately, ESET has succeded reproducing the issue and **provided a fix** today (through pre-release update servers): https://forum.eset.com/topic/6033-windows-10-forget-folder-view-setting-when-ess-is-installed/page-5#entry33407

### Update:

If the Cleaner module doesn't fix the system after a reboot and a startup scan (as it happens on some systems), these are the steps (taken from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcVts87IXMY)) to manually get it fixed:

---

1. Open Regedit:

In regedit go to these 2 destinations:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{42a­edc87-2188-41fd-b9a3-0c966feabec1}\InPro­cServer32\`

and

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{42aedc87-2188-4­1fd-b9a3-0c966feabec1}\InProcServer32\`

2. Start by right-clicking on the last sub-key (which in this case is `InProcServer32`) and click on "Permissions...", then click on "Advanced...", then click on "Change" for the "Owner". Again choose "Advanced...", click "Find Now" and select "Administrators". "OK", "OK". Select the "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" and also "Replace all child object permission entries...", then click OK. Then select "Administrators" in the Permissions window you first opened and tick "Full Control" then hit "OK".
   Do that to the `InProcServer32` folder in both HKEY paths.
3. Double click on `(Default)` and replace `%SystemRoot%\SysWow64\shell32.dll` with `%SystemRoot%\system32\windows.stor­age.dll` in both file destinations, then restart your PC and everything should work fine!!

Answer (score 3):

To save your desktop icons just right click on your Windows' Desktop and select Refresh.

An easy way to restore your desktop icons is to make a batch file with the code below - I called my file RestoreIcons.bat and stored it in a folder on my Windows' path so I could easily run it.

```
@echo off
title Restore Desktop Icons
color 0E
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
cls
echo This will restore desktop icons to position saved since either
echo * last reboot
echo * or last time you right-clicked on desktop and selected Refresh
echo whichever was the most recent.
echo.
echo The main reason for this pause is that a delay was needed between commands 
echo for this batch file to actually work.
echo.
pause  
start explorer.exe
```

Comment: one may simply use PING command to ping 'home' for specified time period, thus allowing for an automated pause

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some difference of opinion on what "works" and what doesn't. It seems that different versions of Windows 10 and various updates to software solutions suggested here work at various times - and not at others.  Which is to say, YMMV. Here is what worked and didn't work for me as of Feb 25, 2018 using Windows 10 version 1709, Home edition, fully updated. I have a dual monitor setup, both at 1920 x 1080, the laptop screen scaled at 150%, the desktop screen scaled at 100% (Windows recommended settings).

- The right-click Desktop and click Refresh option: Didn't work at all for me.  Clicked refresh, moved an icon as a test, killed Explorer, when Explorer came back, the icon was not restored. Fail.
- [Desktop Restore](http://www.midiox.com/index.htm?http://www.midiox.com/desktoprestore.htm) version 1.7.0 from Midi-Ox: Worked, but not    perfectly. Saved the icon layout, changed my primary display to be the desktop monitor (which moves all the icons from the laptop to the external desktop monitor but totally destroys the layout), then did an icon restore. Was mostly good, but two icons wound up on top of each other and one icon was left back on the desktop monitor.
- [DesktopOK](https://www.softwareok.com/?Download=DesktopOK) version 5.01 from SoftwareOK.com: Did the same change-the-primary-display test as described above. DesktopOK performed flawlessly.

Needless to say, DesktopOK is the solution I'm using. Based on other responses here, YMMV. Good luck!

Comment: Dear Bruce, if what you are describing above is what you tried, the refresh didn't work for you because you clicked refresh BEFORE you moved the icon.
you need to click refresh AFTER moving the icon.
the refresh operation is what stores the location into the registry

Comment: @Lockszmith, you are misinterpreting the test I described. I expected the refresh to have saved the icon position BEFORE it was moved. The test was to move the icon, kill Explorer, restart it, and then see if the icon was restored to the old location at the time of the refresh. That didn't work for me.

Comment: I see and stand corrected. Though I presume everyone getting here were looking for a way to preserve something from being lost - at least that was what brought me here.
Sounds like something works better on your env than on mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the registry.

Run `regedit`, go to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop`, right-click the `Desktop` container and click `Export`. Save it to some `.reg` file somewhere.

When you want to restore it just run the `.reg` file and restart `explorer.exe` (or `Windows Explorer`).

Tested on Windows 10.