# Desktop icons always reset after boot

Tags: windows-10, desktop, desktop-icons

Why every time I reboot my Windows 10, the icons on the desktop are reverted on their default position?

I have searched for a solution on Google but without find anything useful.

Comment: Did you try to _"simply right-click the Desktop & click Refresh. This saves the icon positions (at least it does on XP, also confirmed on Windows 7)."_

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force Windows to save desktop icon positions?](http://superuser.com/questions/466661/how-to-force-windows-to-save-desktop-icon-positions)

Answer (score 1):

I often switch the HDMI from my TV to my Monitor or vice versa.
Doing this, the icons are always mixed. Therefore I installed the program '**DesktopOK**', in which you can create profiles for different resolutions and save the state.

There are alternative programs, too, when you google 'saving position desktop icons' or similar.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to right click the desktop where there is no other icons, Select View, and then uncheck Auto arrange icons. Works even after a reboot. I must admit it took me a while since upgrading to Windows 10. It definately works for me.
Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

The solution: Lay out your desktop icons to your preference, then right click on any open area of the desktop to bring up "View", then select a different icon size, Large Medium or Small, I chose Medium from my preferred small.

Once they've changed in size, re-start the PC, and all should be exactly as you left it!